# How to deploy gutenberg on my own

Tags: plugins, deployment

I am new to Wordpress plugin programming and I do not understand how it is possible to create **Gutenberg.zip** from the **Source code (zip)** from [this](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/releases/tag/v10.4.1) link.

Note: Of course I could just download the already deployed version, but I am interested in how the process works.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to search a bit for the build steps. You want [Getting Started with Code Contribution](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/v10.4.1/docs/contributors/code/getting-started-with-code-contribution.md#development-tools-node):

> After installing Node, you can build Gutenberg by running the following from within the cloned repository:
>
> ```
> npm ci
> npm run build
> ```
>
> Note: The install scripts require Python to be installed and in the path of the local system. This might be installed by default for your operating system, or require downloading and installing.
>
> Once built, Gutenberg is ready to be used as a WordPress plugin!

That will build Gutenberg to a working state, but won't filter down the set of files to the distribution .zip. For that you want the script bin/build-plugin-zip.sh

Comment: You kind of left us hanging there...

Comment: D’oh, bad edit - sorry!